# Launch/Clone Powershell console

Tags: .net, powershell, console

Is there a way (command)
to launch a new console from the current one
with all the actual Environment/Context of the current console?

All the variables/connections/configurations of the current console...
the equivalent of cloning the actual console...

Comment: You'll automatically inherit the process environment if you launch PowerShell from within PowerShell - but AFAIK there's no supported way of "cloning" the execution context and session state from a running instance

Comment: thanks Mathias... hope to see a feature like this in future version... something like "New-Console -???"

Comment: It's not gonna happen for Windows PowerShell (version<=5.1), but if you'd like to see that type of functionality in a newer (or perhaps _future_) version of PowerShell I suggest [raising it in an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), which is where PowerShell is being actively developed :-)